# Why we shouldn't take non Muslims as a friend?

Tags: sharia, non-muslim, friendship

"Bismillah"

Somewhere in Quran I found it is written that we shouldn't take non-Muslims as a friend, if we do so then we will become one of them. What is the explanation of it? The thing is we used to meet many non-Muslims in our workplace or the educational institutes and many where. And we consider them as like our friends, the line isn't clear to me. Did Allah mean all non-Muslims or just who do act as non-Muslim in the path of Allah?

Comment: It's totaly wrong not to make non muslim a friend, they are also human and i don't think anywhere in quran it's mentioned not to make friendship with them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you are referring to the verse 5:51 in the Quran:

> *O believers! Do not consider (hostile) Jews and Christians as (your) reliable allies. They (all) are friends to one another (against you). And whoever of you makes friends with them will (also) become one of them. Surely, Allah does not guide the wrongdoing people.*
>   ([Source- Irfan ul Quran](http://www.irfan-ul-quran.com/quran/english/contents/sura/cols/0/ar/1/ur/1/ra/1/en/1/sid/5/Read-Holy-Quran-Sura-5-Al-Maidah-with-English-Urdu-Translations.html))
>   ([Additional translations- Quran Corpus](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=5&verse=51))

The Arabic word used in this ayah, which is sometimes translated as "friend" is *awliya* ([source](http://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=5&verse=51#(5:51:1))).
The word *awliya* is the plural form of *wali*. It's very different from the English word "friend."

I think that you might find [this document](http://alghazzali.org/resources/articles/friendship.pdf) interesting. Take a look at 2e. It expands on what *wali* means. You'll find that you can take non-Muslims as friends, in the casual, amiable that way the word "friend" implies.

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot... this is very helpful.. and thanks you all for clarifying me..

And brother, you got the right thing.. I thought its friend.. but definitely I understood that Im missing something that need more explanations.. actually I love to discuss whenever I get any question or confusion in my mind. 
Thanks a lot.. may Allah bless you all..

Comment: Nice answer, may allah bless you

Answer (score 4):

**What I think you are talking about this ayat:**

> O you who have believed, do not take the Jews and the Christians as allies. They are [in fact] allies of one another. And whoever is an ally to them among you - then indeed, he is [one] of them. Indeed, Allah guides not the wrongdoing people.
>
> **Ayat No 5:51 (Surat Al-Mā'idah)**

In This ayat Allah is talking about those people who plan against Muslims or try to bring harm to Muslims. This does not mean that we should not be friends with them.

In this surat Allah tell identify enemies of Islam. If you study the previous ayat of this Surat you will know what this surat is about.

Don't take ayat from the middle of the surat. Read the context of the ayat. If you don't study the whole ayat then you will know just half of the truth.

Answer (score 1):

Salam
I appreciate the answers of other brothers. They are right. I also wanted to emphasize that the Quranic terms should be understood according to other verses and also to the historical background of the verse. The two other answers dealt with the issue by considering this fact.

There remains one point. Our friends influence us. So, if your non-muslim or even muslim friends discourage you in following Islamic rules or have bad effects on your beliefs or behaviors, you should try to manage the relationship so that you stay away from its harm. Managing the relation doesn't mean necessary to avoid those people but to take good measures to encounter their effect on your soul.

Comment: I do agree with you. From my experience, I have seen a non muslim classmate (he is buddhish) who really disbelieve Allah and any type of God.. and I had a discuss with him, he argued very boldly, tried to make me realize that we are self created and we everyone is like gods in this world and the world is for us. He showed many logics to me. And one day he saw some save motivational verses of quran on my pc while working and really laughed at me, said these are so silly and useless, how will these help us? Where is the relation of this with a religion.

Comment: (he thinks religion is only about prayer, hizab and fasting etc.. few things) I said that our religion isn't about just formalities, it's a lifestyle, Allah explained everything in the Quran, and it will take our whole life to understand these.. 

But I know another friend who is hindu. I've seen he tries to understand.. when I asked him about God, he said there must be one God, since the whole world follows a single rule and so systematic so its not possible that there are lots of Gods.. I guess he might have chances to became a muslim believer in future..

Comment: And I have a muslim cousin who just dont follows the islamic rules, do unwanted things in secrets and its true she appreciates our belief and good works when others prays too, but when Im with her alone she tries to show the examples of the successful people who aren't muslims.. where I jsut always see that most of the successful people have good deeds as muslims, and she often says, no doubt we are going to hell, so why wont we enjoy the rest of our lives? I found she never tries to be changed, she lies a lot and some times praises about others and give sadqah as just to show off.

Comment: I really was surprised after seeing different types of belief among them.. really we never know what lies on others hearts..Allah knows best. Even muslim doesn't mean a real believer.. we should be cautious to justify their belief and intention..

Answer (score -1):

in the name of god

who tell you don't be friends with non-Muslims?!

The Quran said you "shouldn't" accept "kafir" people (the people who's not believe the god or be enemy with god) as friend not 'non-muslims'.
there are many people which believe the god like christians or jewish.
so the meaning of this god's advise is, don't prefer mulsim's friend to non-muslim one. he didn't force you, just an advise

God protect you